# how to group array lists into one

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-arrayadapter

How do you make these two array lists into one array list so that it still works in my arrayAdapter. I cant remember how to go about doing this.

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
        Context context;
        ArrayList<String>mtitle;
        ArrayList<String>mdesc;

        public MyArrayAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String>title, ArrayList<String>desc) {
            super(c, R.layout.single_row, R.id.viewtitle, title);
```

...

Answer (score 0):

use java been type array list.
Like:-

```
public class JBContacts {
    public String strID = "";
    public String strTitle = "";
    public String getStrID() {
        return strID;
    }
    public void setStrID(String strID) {
        this.strID = strID;
    }
    public String getStrTitle() {
        return strTitle;
    }
    public void setStrTitle(String strTitle) {
        this.strTitle = strTitle;
    }

}

ArrayList<JBContacts> mArrayListContacts;
JBContacts mJbContacts;

mArrayListContacts = new ArrayList<JBContacts>();
                mJbContacts = new JBContacts();

                        strId = mJsonObjectContacts.getString(Constants.TAG_ID);
                        strTitle = mJsonObjectContacts
                                .getString(Constants.TAG_TITLE);
                        mJbContacts.setStrTitle(strTitle);
```